# Jest fails when importing a 3rd party non TS module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app, es6-modules, react-scripts

I am using an internal 3rd party Design system library, we will call it (3DS) to render components. The 3DS library doesn't support Typescript, ie. there are no .d.ts files. We are using TS in our project.

I have discovered a way to import the 3DS by disabling TS for one line.

`//@ts-ignore 
import { BrandProvider } from "@3ds/components";`

This technique work fine in the browser. Everything loads up and I can see used components in the view.

However, when I run my test using Jest I get the following errors.

`Cannot find module '@3ds/components' from App.tsx`

So I update the import to use absolute paths to see what happens.

`import { BrandProvider } from '../node_modules/@3ds/components/esm';`

Which give me this error.

```
est encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
```

Thats better because it points me to use transformIgnorePatterns which I believe will ignore transformation of the package, brilliant!

So I add this to my jest config in package.json

```
"transformIgnorePatterns" : ["node_modules/@3ds"]
```

Now admittedly I could play around with the value in the array, but it doesn't matter react-scripts does not support this configuration and here is the evidence.

```
These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App: transformIgnorePatterns
```

As far as I can see I am stuck.
UPDATED, updating to `react-scripts: 3.1.1` allows me to use `transformIgnorePatterns`.

But I still get a error loading `JEST`

What I need
I need Jest/React scripts to be able to import a non TS module into the project and run the tests. Or at least a way to configure Jest to do that.

Comment: There should be nothing preventing you from importing pure js modules, only thing you need to do is state `declare module 3ds;` after the import to make typescript happy. In this case assuming that the imported module adds `3ds` to global. So believe you need to step back a bit and just focus on making typescript compile when using the module.

Comment: No `3ds` is not added to a global object. It imported to any other module and used as a component.

Comment: Alright, then perhaps it would be `declare module BrandProvider`. My point was simply that TypeScript does not require imported modules to be written in ts or have interfaces, you just need to tell the compiler 'I know that something called BrandProvider is available to me'.

Comment: Cool, imoprting the non TS file is no problem the real issue is getting that non TS file to run in JEST

Comment: What is it exactly you are importing cause the Jest error says that the problem usually is attempting to import something that is not plain javascript. Also by the way looks like transformIgnorePatterns is a Babel config.

Comment: Yep I was beginning to think the same thing as you. It's the way the `npm` module is defined. So I import from a `esm` folder with an `es6` `index` that reference a number of modules using the `export { default as PostcodeField } from '@3ds/PostcodeField';` syntax. The individual module has a `dist` and `esm` folder both with `index.js`. The `dist` has `es5` with the `module.export` syntax & the `esm` is obviously using `es6`. I am beginning to think that I need to provide various `index` files for example `cjs.js`

Comment: any solution yet?